# Is SNMP v1 or v2 supported in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: snmp

Can you tell me if Windows 2003 servers support v1 or v2 from snmp and how to use only v2?

Answer (score 0):

As per MS documentation, SNMPv2 is supported from Windows Server 2000 onward.

You can check supported versions on the next [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/snmp/supported-versions).

As for the configuring, please check the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-snmp-service) from the Microsoft docs.